# Second monitor image position problem

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. After a recently Ubuntu update the image on the second monitor is wrong positioned.

[Image on second monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXUTd.jpg)

I tried to modify monitors.cfg to adjust the x position but no effect.

I don't know what else to do. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem got solved by itself after some Ubuntu updates.

Currently my **xorg.conf** file looks like this:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "intel"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option "AccelMethod" "SNA"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
    Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
    Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
EndSection
```

Comment: That is nice you shared your solution. Thank you.